# What if the luminosity of Sunlight increased by 10%

Tags: human-biology

If the luminosity of sunlight increased by 10%, would people be able to survive outside? Would such brightness of light be very harmful to them, for exemple as much as the Mercury Vapour Lamp deprived of its protection from UV light? I omit the temperature issue, I mean radiation itself, because I'm curious whether man (or bacteria) could survive if he went outside completely naked?

Comment: We don't typically like these sorts of speculative questions here, you might be better off at Worldbuilding.SE. That said, there's quite a bit of additional critical thinking you could do here, such as thinking about how the intensity of sunlight changes seasonally and with latitude. Also omitting the "temperature issue" is a pretty big step, but I think I understand that you mean to just talk about UV. Maybe ask on worldbuilding about a planet that got more UV radiation from its star.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really on topic for Biology; I'd suggest another stack like Worldbuilding.

Comment: People from PhysicStackExchange said it would be better to ask this question here. This is the proof that the users in here complain only about the questions etc. No more questions here, promise! Bye bye.

Comment: Well it didn't belong on Physics either - they aren't responsible for determining what is on topic at Biology, they were just trying to help you out.

Comment: If not Worldbuilding, then Earth Science.  But since Earth orbits close to the inner edge of the "Goldilocks Zone", I would guess that a 10% increase in solar radiation might be enough to kick the planet into a Venus-like runaway greenhouse.  If that doesn't happen, then sure, humans could survive outside on most of the planet, just as they do in tropical areas today.

Answer (score 1):

From the [total luminocity at ground level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Measurement) ~$1000\space W/m^2$ only $3-5\%$ consititute of UV-rays, so UV part is $30-50 W/m^2$. Hence increase of luminocity for $10\%$ means that UV part will increase to $3 - 5\space W/m^2$ so it is quite miniscule increase if we are talking about going naked outdoors. E.g.  [tanning beds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_tanning) however have different spectra have stronger UV components than current Sun radiation.